# What does `failed to download database [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb` mean when launching Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks, elasticsearch-5

I deployed an Elasticsearch cluster in AWS EKS with 3 nodes. After launching the cluster, I can see 3 pods are running but 2 of them running fine, one of them keep failing and terminating and restarting.

Below is the error log on the failed pod.

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-12-26T08:17:33,061Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.i.g.DatabaseRegistry", "cluster.name": "elk", "node.name": "elk-es-node-1", "message": "downloading geoip database [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb] to [/tmp/elasticsearch-9470345091343635510/geoip-databases/HoGUMQ9ISsCjQ4KhIL2IFA/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb.tmp.gz]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-12-26T08:17:33,070Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.i.g.DatabaseRegistry", "cluster.name": "elk", "node.name": "elk-es-node-1", "message": "failed to download database [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]",
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:179) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedRaiseException(ClusterBlocks.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.executeSearch(TransportSearchAction.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.executeLocalSearch(TransportSearchAction.java:494) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.lambda$executeRequest$3(TransportSearchAction.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.query.Rewriteable.rewriteAndFetch(Rewriteable.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.query.Rewriteable.rewriteAndFetch(Rewriteable.java:76) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.executeRequest(TransportSearchAction.java:329) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:217) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:173) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ActionFilter$Simple.apply(ActionFilter.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:171) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:149) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:402) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.FilterClient.doExecute(FilterClient.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.OriginSettingClient.doExecute(OriginSettingClient.java:40) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:402) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.search(AbstractClient.java:534) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.DatabaseRegistry.lambda$retrieveDatabase$11(DatabaseRegistry.java:359) [ingest-geoip-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:678) [elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-12-26T08:17:33,295Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.l.LicenseService", "cluster.name": "elk", "node.name": "elk-es-node-1", "message": "license [8a88ef40-3b0b-439e-9f46-32e911999b7d] mode [basic] - valid" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-12-26T08:17:33,309Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport", "cluster.name": "elk", "node.name": "elk-es-node-1", "message": "publish_address {elk-es-node-1.elk-es-node.default.svc/10.0.1.182:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}", "cluster.uuid": "hqRP62pNTze1IWQ0sOOR2Q", "node.id": "HoGUMQ9ISsCjQ4KhIL2IFA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-12-26T08:17:33,310Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elk", "node.name": "elk-es-node-1", "message": "started", "cluster.uuid": "hqRP62pNTze1IWQ0sOOR2Q", "node.id": "HoGUMQ9ISsCjQ4KhIL2IFA"  }
```

The error message says `failed to download database [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]` but I don't know what does this mean.

Below is my Elasticsearch K8S spec file.

```yaml
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elk
spec:
  version: 7.15.2
  serviceAccountName: docker-sa
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  nodeSets:
  - name: node
    count: 3
    config:
      network.host: 0.0.0.0
      xpack.security.enabled: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - bash
              - -c
              - /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/readiness-probe-script.sh
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 12
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 12
          env:
          - name: READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT
            value: "120"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 4Gi
          volumeMounts:
          - name: elasticsearch-data
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: ebs-sc
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1024Gi
```

Any idea why this happens?

I have provisioned a cluster of nodes (ec2 instance) with 2 desired count and 3 maximum. At the moment, only 2 nodes are launched.

Below is the output of nodes information:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                            STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
ip-10-0-1-216.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   6d16h   v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
ip-10-0-2-24.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   6d17h   v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b

$ kubectl describe node ip-10-0-1-216.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Name:               ip-10-0-1-216.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.xlarge
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=elk
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-045371401c5f70a1e
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2a
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-1-216.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.xlarge
                    topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=ap-southeast-2a
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2a
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"ebs.csi.aws.com":"i-0fd067997eddeaf86"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:29:13 +1100
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  ip-10-0-1-216.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:51 +1100
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Mon, 27 Dec 2021 20:44:02 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:29:13 +1100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:29:13 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:29:34 +1100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.0.1.216
  Hostname:     ip-10-0-1-216.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  ip-10-0-1-216.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         4
  ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      16205904Ki
  pods:                        58
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         3920m
  ephemeral-storage:           18242267924
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      15189072Ki
  pods:                        58
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 ec2ac34dd2e6a84bdc340dd6a62c3514
  System UUID:                ec2ac34d-d2e6-a84b-dc34-0dd6a62c3514
  Boot ID:                    26c6dde2-1131-4068-9265-c0c4e12d54d3
  Kernel Version:             5.4.156-83.273.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://20.10.7
  Kubelet Version:            v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-southeast-2a/i-0fd067997eddeaf86
Non-terminated Pods:          (14 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                            CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                            ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  cert-manager                cert-manager-68ff46b886-tzfqw                   0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d16h
  cert-manager                cert-manager-cainjector-7cdbb9c945-w99rf        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d16h
  cert-manager                cert-manager-webhook-58d45d56b8-wsmwp           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d16h
  default                     elk-es-node-0                                   1 (25%)       100m (2%)   4Gi (27%)        50Mi (0%)      3d16h
  default                     sidecar-66f887c666-pbbcv                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d19h
  elastic-system              elastic-operator-0                              100m (2%)     1 (25%)     150Mi (1%)       512Mi (3%)     3d16h
  kube-system                 aws-load-balancer-controller-9c59c86d8-jd6j9    100m (2%)     200m (5%)   200Mi (1%)       500Mi (3%)     3d16h
  kube-system                 aws-node-hpnxj                                  10m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d14h
  kube-system                 cluster-autoscaler-76fd4db4c-lcff5              100m (2%)     100m (2%)   600Mi (4%)       600Mi (4%)     3d16h
  kube-system                 coredns-68f7974869-x4kxs                        100m (2%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (1%)     3d16h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-controller-55b9f85d5c-c94m5             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d16h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-controller-55b9f85d5c-mt57k             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d16h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-node-692n6                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d13h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-cqll5                                100m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         4d14h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         1510m (38%)   1400m (35%)
  memory                      5116Mi (34%)  1832Mi (12%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0             0
Events:                       <none>

Name:               ip-10-0-2-24.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.xlarge
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=elk
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-045371401c5f70a1e
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2b
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-2-24.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.xlarge
                    topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=ap-southeast-2b
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2b
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"ebs.csi.aws.com":"i-0bac62ee2ae10a59a"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:23:12 +1100
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  ip-10-0-2-24.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:26:12 +1100
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Mon, 27 Dec 2021 20:23:13 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:23:12 +1100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:23:12 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Fri, 31 Dec 2021 13:25:52 +1100   Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:23:32 +1100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.0.2.24
  Hostname:     ip-10-0-2-24.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  ip-10-0-2-24.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         4
  ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      16205904Ki
  pods:                        58
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         3920m
  ephemeral-storage:           18242267924
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      15189072Ki
  pods:                        58
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 ec29ef8b81ba9ab1229c8348fa8f6c97
  System UUID:                ec29ef8b-81ba-9ab1-229c-8348fa8f6c97
  Boot ID:                    8bf36296-625d-4749-8e81-abe0d7dd85c8
  Kernel Version:             5.4.156-83.273.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://20.10.7
  Kubelet Version:            v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-southeast-2b/i-0bac62ee2ae10a59a
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                          CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                          ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     elk-es-node-1                 1 (25%)       100m (2%)   4Gi (27%)        50Mi (0%)      3d16h
  default                     kibana-kb-7f66d6978d-6knrx    100m (2%)     100m (2%)   1Gi (6%)         1Gi (6%)       3d16h
  default                     transform-798f5758cd-4x94w    1 (25%)       0 (0%)      2Gi (13%)        0 (0%)         6d16h
  kube-system                 aws-node-qmfg7                10m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6d17h
  kube-system                 coredns-68f7974869-wqs2k      100m (2%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (1%)     3d16h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-node-48h2n            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6d17h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-f99dh              100m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6d17h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         2310m (58%)   200m (5%)
  memory                      7238Mi (48%)  1244Mi (8%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0             0
Events:                       <none>
```

Comment: Could you please check if you have enough resources on that node (`kubectl describe node`)?

Comment: Do you mean the cpu and memory could be a problem? I have updated the question for the number of nodes in the cluster. Usually I see insufficient memory or cpu error if it is running out of resources.

Comment: Could you please show the output of the command I mentioned before? (We are interested in `Allocated resources`). My question aimed to get to know if the problem was connected with Elasticsearch or insufficient resources.

Comment: Yes I have added it in the post thanks